# Bootstrap Max Viewport with Scrolling Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There's a specific layout I'm trying to achieve in Bootstrap but can't quite nail it down.

My requirements are:

1. Browser window must not scroll.
2. Display must be 100% of browser height.
3. Menu, Left contents, and Right contents columns must scroll independently.

My desired layout
[looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIhUb.png)

Here's my code so far:

```
html,body{height:100%; color: white;}
.bg-purple { background: rgb(48,0,50); }
.bg-gray { background: rgb(74,74,74); }
.bg-blue { background: rgb(50,101,196); }
.bg-red { background: rgb(196,50,53); }
.bg-green { background: rgb(50,196,53); }

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-2 bg-gray h-100" style="overflow-y: auto;">
            menu<br />menu<br />menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 bg-green h-100">
            <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple flex-shrink-0">
                    MY HEIGHT SHOULD CHANGE<br />BASED ON CONTENT.<br />NO ABSOLUTE HEIGHT SETTINGS.
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center flex-grow-1 mh-100">
                    <div class="col bg-blue mh-100" id="left" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                        <p><strong>THIS AREA SHOULD SCROLL INDEPENDENTLY</strong></p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents END</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col bg-red mh-100" id="right" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                         <p><strong>THIS AREA SHOULD SCROLL INDEPENDENTLY</strong></p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents END</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".scrollableDiv").css("max-height", "calc(100vh - " + $("#header").height() + "px)")
})
```

```css
#container{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>html,body{height:100%; color: white;}
.bg-purple { background: rgb(48,0,50); }
.bg-gray { background: rgb(74,74,74); }
.bg-blue { background: rgb(50,101,196); }
.bg-red { background: rgb(196,50,53); }
.bg-green { background: rgb(50,196,53); }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-2 bg-gray h-100" style="overflow-y: auto;">
            menu<br />menu<br />menu
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 bg-green h-100">
            <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple flex-shrink-0" id="header">
                    MY HEIGHT SHOULD CHANGE<br />BASED ON CONTENT.<br />NO ABSOLUTE HEIGHT SETTINGS.
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="col bg-blue scrollableDiv" id="left" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                        <p><strong>THIS AREA SHOULD SCROLL INDEPENDENTLY</strong></p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents</p><p>Left contents END</p>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col bg-red scrollableDiv" id="right" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                         <p><strong>THIS AREA SHOULD SCROLL INDEPENDENTLY</strong></p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents</p><p>Right contents END</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Joao,

Thanks so much for your answer!

i meant to add that i was hoping to avoid using JS. Do you know if that's possible? If not, i'm happy to mark this as solved.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hello John, thanks for your feedback. Well, it's possible doing just CSS, but you would need to insert a fixed value in this code:

From this (JS)
calc(100vh - " + $("#header").height() + "px);

To this (in CSS)
calc(100vh - 72px);

in example

Comment: That's sort of what i figured. :/ Thanks so much for your help on this!

Comment: You're welcome, anything you need, we are here!